# confusion between A-SI TFT vs IPS TFT

Tags: laptop

Recently I have decided to upgrade my laptop screen and after doing some research I have found [BOE NV156FHM-N61](https://www.panelook.com/NV156FHM-N61_BOE_15.6_LCM_overview_29824.html#NV156FHM-N61_Compatible_Models) as a candidate. One of the major reason i am upgrading is because my current display is TN panel and hence having severe viewing angle issue, so this candidate has to be **IPS** to resolve the problem. The confusion here is that the website i mentioned is saying that the  panel type as **a-si TFT**, while others are saying its IPS, even my local shop is sayig it is IPS. I have heard TFT-LCD and IPS LCDs are completely different. Can somebody clear this confusion? also the panel i mentioned is really IPS or something alternative to IPS? I am looking for a **REAL IPS**, not any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The NV156FHM-N61 is an IPS panel.**

TFT (thin-film-transistor) LCDs are the dominant panel technology for all LCDs. Both IPS and TN panels are types of TFT panels. In other words, all IPS panels are TFT panels, but not all TFT panels are IPS panels.